# Importing mail from Tbird 12.04 t0 ubuntu 16.04to new

Tags: email

I need to import my Tbird mail and settings from my old Ubuntu 12.04 to new Ubuntu Tbird in 16.04. How is this done?

I have saved my .tbird folder from 12.04, and tried to copy the .default folder and paste it in to the new .default folder.  This used to work years ago.  Message says profile is missing.

Please help...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure the **Thunderbird** isn't running.  Then launch it from the commandline with the `-profilemanager` argument.

```
$ thunderbird -profilemanager
```

1. Click on the Button to **Create Profile**.
2. Click **Next**
3. Type in the name you want to Call this Profile.
4. Click **Choose Folder**
5. Browse to where you have copied this folder.  Select it and click **OPEN**
6. Click **Finish**
7. Click **Start Thunderbird**.

The new configuration will be your Default Profile that will start when you Launch Thunderbird.  You can change the default by running Thunderbird with the `-profilemanager` argument if you decide to use a different one.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I'm still without my old settings.  I get the message in the terminal: The config file XML does not contain an email account configuration.
-- Exception object --
+  (string) The config file XML does not contain an email account configuration.*

Comment: I hit enter instead, sorry.

Comment: It's not clear to me where you are stuck.  Which # step brings the error message you describe?

Comment: It asks me if I want to create a new profile.  Should I say Yes or Use existing one.  Should I copy the whole folder .thunderbird?  When I copy that to my desktop it doesn't show because it is a hidden file.  I'm lost on what to do...  Thanks

Comment: It doesn't matter where you put the files from your previous installation.  By default there will be a profile in the `.thunderbird` folder from your previous OS.  The profile(s) will be listing something similar to these items: `gpgal8pl.alassane`, `lj7p62iq.default`, `nohaedtg.L. D. James`.  I have a number of profiles in my `.thunderbird` folder that I can choose from.  You can put the folders that you see that resemble those names into your current system's `.thunderbird` folder.  Then add one of those using the steps in the answer.

Comment: It worked!  Thank You L.D. James for having patience with me.  I'm just a wannabe nerd, and at this rate, I'll never be one. Thanks again...  Ralph

Comment: Glad it worked!  You can consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey checkmark  so that others can see a resolution that works.